# codeigniter library load error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 3.0.1. I've created a library (`application/libraries/Someclass.php`); the code is as follows:

```
<?php  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Someclass
{
    public function some_method()
    {
        $data = array(
            'India' => 'India',
            'Srilanka' => 'Srilanka',
            'Maldives' => 'Maldives',
            'Nepal' => 'Nepal',
            'Pakistan' => 'Pakistan'
            );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to get this from the view:

```
<?php $this->load->library('someclass');?>
<?php var_dump($this->someclass->some_method());?>
```

I get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function country() on null

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post you controller code???

Comment: It looks like there's something else causing your issue; where do you call `country()` in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php $this->load->library('Someclass');?>
```

Comment: Please check this link http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html